# add some javascript inside a html anchor tag href element

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

Quick javascript question...

I wont bore you with the need for this (lets just say IE) but I need the following HTML:

```
href="includes/jwplayer/player.swf?3&amp;file=nicki.mp4"
```

to have a random number generated via javascript where '3' is in the above example. So like:

```
href="includes/jwplayer/player.swf?[RANDOM NUMBER CODE HERE]&amp;file=nicki.mp4"
```

I know the js code is:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
```

But how can I fit this in with the Html?

Is the only answer some php (or similar)?

A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If *"fit this in with the Html"* means *"add a random number to every link that looks like this"*, then something like this would do it:

```
$("a[href^=includes/jwplayer/player.swf]").attr("href", function (i, s) {
  return s.replace( /\?\d*&?/, "?" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + "&" );
})
```

If it's not `<a>` elements that carry the `href` in your case, change the selector accordingly.

The regex says:

```
\?   # a question mark
\d*  # any number of digits (to replace what's already there)
&?   # an optional ampersand
```

Comment: Nice method, Personally I would of dynamically changed the whole `href` depending on a data-file value, +1

Comment: Is that jQuery? I think you need the `attr()` method, don't believe there's one for `href`

Comment: @Russ: Whoops, of course. Thanks for reminding me. (fixed now)

Comment: Also, will you not lose the file parameter ?

Comment: @Robert: No, as this replaces only the relevant part of the string. All parts not matched by the regex will stay the same.

Comment: You didn't have the ampersand in there in your previous revision.

Comment: Ta for the quick response all, but the above jQuery gives me the js error 's.replace is not a function'. Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: Also, the callback contains a key and a value so you would have to use: `function (k,s){}`, and that will also fix your problem Adi

Comment: @Robert: I had a comment about the ampersand being missing in the regex, I removed it after revising my answer. OBTW, if you *knew* where the mistake was, you could have said straigt-away instead of "testing" me. ;-)

Comment: I had good faith my friend :), I don't like taking the light away from the original correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could set it via client script, but this will break if the user has JavaScript turned off. It would be better to set it from the server side, which sounds like PHP in your case.

Comment: +1, That's what I would do as well. If it is just a cache-breaker, you could do it on the client side as well, but doing it on the server will be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

with native javascript you could put in a "not random" link and randomize it with the setAttiribute method native to JavaScript

```
var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
document.getElementById('an-id-of-the-link').setAttribute('href', 'includes/jwplayer/player.swf?' + r + '&amp;file=nicki.mp4');
```

note that with older versioned browsers selecting the object becomes harder so getElementById is one of the few ways that is safe along most of the browsers.

Comment: This is not a good solution as the file parameter would obviously change

Comment: in both cases the file name or path would be served out of a server-side language. filling it in only the link or also putting it into the script would also fit it would be just as easy to just replace the file name (aka currently presented in 'file=nicki.mp4'). you do have a point it is not going to be pretty.